# Performing an update with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am digging into LINQ--trying to understand basic models (it seems pretty cool to me). The code below is the code to perform before committing an update.

```
   Linq01.Account acc = context.Accounts.Single( pc => pc.AccountID == AccountID );
   acc.Name = textboxAccountNameRead.Text.Trim();
   context.SubmitChanges();
```

So far, so good. But what do you do if the Single() method failed--if the account ID wasn't found?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `SingleOrDefault`, if the query does not return a value you can check it against null:

```
var acc = context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(pc => pc.AccountId == AccountId);
if(acc != null)
{
  acc.Name = textboxAccountNameRead.Text.Trim();
  context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Damn. I just did that with a select operation this morning. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Slace's answer, if you call Single and then account ID wasn't found, it will throw an exception. In *some* cases that's more appropriate than returning null and explicitly handling it.